# Открытие активити по нажатию на маркер

Tags: google-maps-api

Как Сделать возможным открытие нового активити при нажатии  на маркер? Не информационное окно,  а именно новое  активити

Answer (score 0):

Можно, например, так:

```
@Override
public boolean onMarkerClick(Marker marker) {
        marker.hideInfoWindow();
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, NewActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        return false;
}
```